# What is the encryption key of key3.db database in firefox profile?

Tags: firefox, encryption, passwords

I want to open key3.db in SQLite browser which store the key for encryption of saved password in firfox, but I see this error: "File is encrypted or not a SQLite3 database or encryption key does not match"

I think key3.db is encrypted. Can anybody tell me what is the Encryption key of this database?

Answer (score 4):

It is not encrypted, it is stored using firefox's .db format (shows up as a Berkeley db according to "file").  [Thunderbird pass decryptor](http://securityxploded.com/thunderbirdpassdecryptor.php) will decrypt this value.
[Additional reference](http://tipstrickshack.blogspot.com/2013/09/extract-decrypt-passwords-from-firefox.html)